# Memory Ordering Effects for Mono/Flux Stream

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I encountered one scenario in one webflux project which stuck me as I'm still new on project-reactor.

The code is like:

```
class InputArg {
    private List<String> list;
    private ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> map;
    // getter setters...
}
final int CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 4;
  ​
0. var someInputArgwithNullMap = ... // init one InputArg object with null map
1. Mono.just(someInputArgwithNullMap)
2.     .flatMapMany((InputArg inputArg) -> {
3.            // inputArg.map == null
4.            inputArg.setMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
5
6.            return Flux.fromIterable(inputArg.getList()).
7.                       .flatMap(str -> {
8.                            // some async call to external service with this str argument
9.                            Mono<String> message = ...
10.                           int randomInteger = ... // code to get random    
11.                           return message.map(msg -> {
12.                             inputArg.getMap().putIfAbsent(msg, randomInteger);
13.                             
14.                             return msg
15.                           });                              
16.                      }, CONCURRENCY_LEVEL);
17. })
18. .map(...) //some operation that modify inputArg again
19. .subscribe(...); //subscriber which needs updated someInputArgwithNullMap and also print 
20. //every msg.
```

My question is:

As Flux.flatMap in line 7 is async processing and maybe running with multi threads different than parent Mono stream, so I use concurrentHashMap in line 4 and atomic operation in line 12 to guarantee syncronized operation on this shared map within inputArg.

But,

1. How about the object inputArg itself between line 4 and line 12 under multithreading context. So the thread in line 4 and line 12 maybe still different, is the change in line 4 visible to line 12 and not possible to throw NPE or other race condition under any PC model even in weak ordering machine like DEC or ARM?
2. The internal mechanism which makes the changes under Mono.flatMap (line 2) visible to line 17's map for that transformed Flux?

I've read several posts through internet and now I know that there're some ordering guarantee between onNext signals so that some setup of syn/volatile or perhaps memory barrier compatiable to new Java 9+ VarHandle api with onNext call. But how to infer the exact memory ordering effect from this prerequisite for my code snippet between some operators. Also one constraint: as compatible reason we cannot modify InputArg to immutable. Wait and appreciate your answers.

**2021-11-20 Update**:

Since line 9 maybe affect multithreading, so furthur clarify this async call:

a. an async call to another reactive service like WebFlux using webClient; or

b. an async call to external cache service using Spring Data Redis.

**2021-11-21 Update:**

After some research, for question 2, my own understanding:

a) According to this statement from WebFlux doc (see the copyright from Pivotal, Inc on the index page https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/index.html) https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html:

"At runtime, a reactive pipeline is formed where data is processed sequentially, in distinct stages. A key benefit of this is that it frees applications from having to protect mutable state because application code within that pipeline is never invoked concurrently."

Seems like this statement also implied that between parent/child stream there's also happens-before relationship (as if in distinct stages).

b. And I checked internal source code of map operator, this method (see Apache 2 licence https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

public Object scanUnsafe(Attr key)

returns Attr.RunStyle.SYNC so that no thread change happens for this operator, which also is default for most of the other operators. So that map operator will see any change made by that flatMapMany on line 2.

For my question 1:

a. Line 9's call maybe change thread only if it has one publishOn operator (subscribeOn will make the whole parent-child stream using one thread through its schedular), and after I checked publishOn's internal code and it has one write/get relationship on one volatile value field between its getting parent onNext signal and its sending signal downstream (which may change thread), so that line 4's change visible to line 12's getMap() method, so that my code is thread-safe.

b. From that statement from WebFlux official doc and also one statement from reactive stream specification (see its MIT No Attribution copyright https://github.com/aws/mit-0) https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#1.3

"onSubscribe, onNext, onError and onComplete signaled to a Subscriber MUST be signaled serially."

seems like also guarantee happens-before relationship between parent/child onNext signal.

c. there's no way to resubscribe the same subscription.

Please correct me if any of my understanding is wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` will produce a `Flux` that respects the Reactive Streams specification, where each outgoing `onNext` has a happens-before relationship with the other. this is done internally by draining a concurrent MPSC queue.

that guarantee stops at the point where each inner `Mono` publishes its value to the `flatMap` coordinator, though.

for example, it is totally possible that 2 inner Monos are subscribed by the coordinator and execute in parallel in two different threads. shared resources used by these Mono could then be under contention.

the `Function` that produces an inner `Mono` out of an incoming `InputArg` is also executed serially, but that's only representing the assembly phase, not the execution phase of said inner Monos.

NB: I'm using `Mono` here because that matches your example. this is true of any `Publisher`